# Any tips for speeding up JBoss when launched from Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, jboss

Normally, jboss takes just under a minute to start up from the command line, but when I start it in debug mode from Eclipse it takes over 2 minutes which can be a right pain when your just trying to debug a quick config change.

Does anyone have any tips for making JBoss start any quicker?

I'm using JBoss 5.1.0GA using the "all" profile, Java 1.6 & Eclipse 3.6

Comment: Which version of JBoss? Which configuration of jboss? Which version of Java?

Comment: Hi Stuart.  On my machine, this is because Eclipse (WTP) insists on building a new EAR file every time I start JBoss.  I have not yet been able to find a way to prevent this :-(.

Comment: Can you test locally using Jetty - or are you using the full JEE feature set provided by JBoss?

Comment: Joel, we do use a lot of the J2EE features, as well as things like JBossESB & Drools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hava a look at the [JBoss 5.x Tuning/Slimming](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/jboss5xtuningslimming) article. Less services need less time to initialize.

You could also use 'exploded' deployment to save the time for building an ear. Seam uses an embedded JBOss for unittesting (TestNG), maybe you find further tricks there.

Answer (score 0):

Double click your server under "Servers" tab in Eclipse, select "Open Launch configuration" under "General Information", in the dialog box "Edit Configuration", you can config the -Xms, -Xmx e.g. in "VM arguments" to speed up your server.